# Three JS ObitControls inside JQuery Draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js

I have a canvas with some cubes inside a draggable element and I want to rotate the camera with `OrbitControls`, but instead of just rotating the cubes it starts also dragging by left click (I want to drag only while clicking on the border).

The [code](http://jsfiddle.net/myrluk3/MAEvS/218/).

Comment: Why do we need `OrbitControl` and so if the camera without it and so turns?

Comment: I need to rotate the camera.

Comment: the camera already rotates

Comment: Yes, but I want to rotate the camera without moving the canvas. I want to move the canvas just by dragging at the border.

Comment: >I want to move the canvas just by dragging at the border. - then at first make it

Comment: That's the problem why I wrote here. If you check this: http://jsfiddle.net/myrluk3/MAEvS/221/, with TrackballControls is working, except the rotation...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69101/discussion-between-istvan-and-almaz-vildanov).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just modify the `THREE.OrbitControls.onMouseMove` and  `THREE.OrbitControls.onMouseDown` methods. Add `event.stopPropagation()` after the `event.preventDefault()`